# mysqladmin: Unknown command: 'status;'

Tags: mysql, mysqladmin

My problem :

```
   C:\Users\Dom>C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -uroot  status;
```

**C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: Unknown command: 'status;'**

I want to see status my mysql connection. 
How to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
C:\Users\Dom>C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -uroot  status
```

Without `;`!